# How to compile NAppGUI using MinGW-W64 on windows

Tags: c, user-interface, cmake, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile NAppGUI ([nappgui.com](https://nappgui.com/en/home/web/home.html)) using MinGW-W64. I've followed instructions to [download](https://nappgui.com/en/download/download.html#h1) source as described. [Here](https://nappgui.com/en/start/quick.html) is instructions to build it using cmake and Visual Studio. There is no any instruction to compile it with MinGW. I'm not familiar with cmake, but I tried to generate mingw makefile using cmake-gui. I got `CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.`
Please help me to build NAppGUI with MinGW-W64

**UPDATE**
My compiler MinGW-w64 was not added to %path% variable. That's why I got `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set` error.
After adding compiler path to %path% variable I'm getting `CMake Error at ...../nappgui_src-main/prj/CMakeCompilers.txt:109 (message): Unknown compiler` error.

**UPDATE 2**
At the moment, MinGW is not "officially" supported by this project. [github issue link](https://github.com/frang75/nappgui_src/issues/5#issuecomment-1008343254). So I think it is not possible to use CMAKE to build it with minGW. If anybody tried to  to compile NAppGUI using MinGW-W64 and has any workarounds please let me know.

Comment: Did you install MinGW at all?

Comment: @thebusybee I'm running MinGW-W64 in portable mode. Now I added it to %path% variable. Now I'm getting `Unknown compiler' error.

Comment: What does the line 109 of "CMakeCompilers.txt" look like? If you think it is relevant, add a few lines above and below. Does it give you some hint, why MinGW's GCC is not recognized?

Comment: @thebusybee line 109 throws 'unknown compiler' error if compiler is other than  Visual studio in windows platform. I'll try visual studio.  thanks for your help. I'll leave this question here, someone may looking for the same.

Comment: You should add an actual answer and mark it. SO is not a forum. This way other visitors can see upfront in the list of questions that you found at least the reason.

Comment: @thebusybee I tried to post my 'update2' as an answer. But SO not accepting answer from my account. I am new to Stackoverflow, I am not aware of all rules and procedures.

Comment: Really? I thought you are allowed to answer any question, including your own, right from the start. Don't you have the big edit field below all these comments under the title "Your Answer"?

Comment: I'm facing answer ban. Whenever I login SO does not allow me to post any answer due to my past bad answers.

Comment: Well, then you must have ignored all hints how to behave. ;-) I don't think that this ban is permanent, so you might want to read some of the [help] to learn when the ban is removed. "_I am not aware of all rules and procedures_" is no excuse, you want to take the [tour]. Behave as in real life, if you are new to a site, be polite and careful.